# pandas add index to column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with about 100 columns that repeat itself because the data is organized by weeks, it looks something like that:

| hours | hours | clicks | clicks | days | days | minutes | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| week 1 | week 2 | week 1 | week 2 | week 1 | week 2 | week 1 | week 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 9 | 3 |

I would like the output to look like this:

| hours_w1 | hours_w2 | clicks_w1 | clicks_w2 | days_w1 | days_w2 | minutes_w1 | minutes_w2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 9 | 3 |

I know I can just rename the columns but because I have over 100 columns I'm looking for a more efficient way.

I tried to use add_suffix but had only managed to add the same suffix to all columns, when what I need is a different index for each week.

any idea how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` for clarity, it's unclear whether you have a MultiIndex of data as header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the suffixes from the first row then add them to the column names and finally remove the first row.

```
# To fix mangle_dup_cols
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]
suffixes = '_' + df.iloc[0].str[0] + df.iloc[0].str[-1]
df.columns += suffixes
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  hours_w1 hours_w2 clicks_w1 clicks_w2 days_w1 days_w2 minutes_w1 minutes_w2
1        2        2         2         3       6       2          2          3
2        1        7         6         3       8       2          9          3
```

Comment: thanks! It works well for the first column (with _w1) but for the second column (for week 2), I get this: hours.1_w2. any idea why it add the .1 and how to remove it?

Comment: The problem is when you read the file with `read_csv` or `read_excel`. Try before `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

first you should change the first row:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x:'w1' if x == 'week 1' else 'w2')
```

Then you can merge it with the column name like this:

```
df.columns = [i + '_' + j for i, j in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])]
```

And then you can remove the first row:

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```